# WFS Getting more than 1 layer

Tags: wfs, mapserver

using Web Feature service and I'm wondering is there a way using get requests to pull multiple features. For example, this WFS http://demo.mapserver.org/cgi-bin/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0 contains 2 layers/features:

Cities

Continents

Could anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Comment: You have posted this to Meta GIS SE so I am migrating it to the Main GIS SE.

Comment: I would start by reading the WFS standards which are available from http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs. Several TypeNames can be used in GetFeature but I am not sure when it is useful.

Comment: Currently writing a program, I just wanted to see if i could do it, and if my program was smart enough to work out its two different layers and represent them differently .

Comment: Did you look at the MapServer help pages for example http://mapserver.org/ogc/wfs_server.html, which shows a query for the same test service that returns multiple features. Not sure though if this is what you are asking, or if you want something more complex?

Answer (score 1):

Separate multiple layers in your request with a comma:

http://demo.mapserver.org/cgi-bin/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=getfeature&TYPENAME=continents,cities&MAXFEATURES=500